# Using boost::options without giving argument value

Tags: c++, boost, flags

I would like running program using boost::program_option without giving value (only flag). 
Like that (here are some other flags):

```
./main.x -b -f test.txt -r 26
```

Now you have to write:

```
./main.x -b 1 -f test.txt -r 26
```

Keyword is (-b). I don`t want to write e.g. 1.

Sample:

```
// boost fields
boost::program_options::variables_map fMap;
boost::program_options::options_description fOptions;

// Add some options to fOptions
fOptions.add_options()
("progressBar,b", po::value<int>(), "Progress bar.");
// some other options

boost::program_options::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, fOptions), fMap);

if(fMap.count("progressBar"))
{
  int l_progressBar = fMap["progressBar"].as<int>();
  if(l_progressBar == 1)
  {
    // some staff
  }
}

//I would like to have something like that:
fOptions.add_options()
("progressBar,b", po::value<void>(), "Progress bar.");

if(fMap.count("progressBar"))
{
  // check if flag (-b) was set and do some staff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two-parameter `operator()` should do the trick:

```
fOptions.add_options()
("progressBar,b", "Progress bar.");
```